# How to remove 'Show When Run' option when using ios shortcut

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I'm implementing ios shortcut intentents. i just add intent in myProject and i don't want to show 'Show When Run' in shortcut option.

how to remove 'show when run' option?

Comment: Hey there, did you manage to find a solution to this?